# UIStackView behaves different on iPhone 11 and iPhone 14 Pro

Tags: ios, uistackview

I have this simple horizontal `UIStackView` added using interface builder, which has a `UIImageView` and a `UILabel` in it. `UIImageView` has greater content hugging priority and content compression resistance priority.

[image]

When I run this on iPhone 14 Pro (iOS 16.1), it works as expected. But it doesn't work properly on iPhone 11 (iOS 16.1).

[image]

I've fixed it using Fill Distribution. What I'm trying to learn is, how is this even possible with the same iOS version?

I've added a minimal reproducible example [here](https://github.com/osrl/stackview-example)

Comment: Is that Horizontal stack view an arrangedSubview of a Vertical stack view (along with the fields and button)? Do you have a width and/or height constraint set on the image view? Or label? Does it lay-out correctly if you use `Distribution: Fill` instead of `Fill Proportionally`?

Comment: It's in an vertical stack view. yes Imageview has width and height constraint. yes it does work with fill distribution. What I'm trying to learn is how is this possible with the same iOS version

Comment: We would need to see it. Put together a [mre] (shouldn't take more than 5 minutes) and post it to somewhere such as GitHub

Comment: I've added a reproducible example. Also changed the screenshot generated with the example code.

Answer (score 0):

Couple weird issues in your layout...

First, there is no need to constrain the "inner" Horizontal stack view's Trailing to the "outer" Vertical stack view's Trailing.

Second, you set an explicit Width constraint on the imageView to `18`, but then you put it in a Horizontal stackView with `Distribution: Fill Proportionally`. Those two settings contradict each other.

When running that app on both `iPhone 14 Pro` and `iPhone 11`, we get auto-layout error/warning messages in the debug console - although slightly different between devices.

Now, why it ***displays*** differently, I don't know. It should display **wrong** on both. I don't have enough phones to run the same comparison on physical devices, so it *might* be Simulator related.

Anyway, take a look at this -- I replicated your layout, but left all elements at their default Hugging and Compression Resistance priorities, removed the extra constraint, and changed the stack view to ``Distribution: Fill`:

[image]

iPhone 11 / 14 Pro comparison (simulators):

[image]

Here's the source to the Storyboard if you want to inspect it closer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="21225" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="cO8-fM-WKB">
    <device id="retina6_1" orientation="portrait" appearance="light"/>
    <dependencies>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="21207"/>
        <capability name="Safe area layout guides" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="System colors in document resources" minToolsVersion="11.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--Login View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="sv4-3A-w2k">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="cO8-fM-WKB" customClass="LoginViewController" customModule="Example" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="b2G-FR-GWS">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="414" height="896"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" axis="vertical" alignment="top" spacing="28" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="ENa-iE-NqQ" userLabel="OutAStackView">
                                <rect key="frame" x="32" y="126" width="350" height="18"/>
                                <subviews>
                                    <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" distribution="fillProportionally" alignment="center" spacing="6" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="SQQ-H3-h7m" userLabel="InAStackView">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="350" height="18"/>
                                        <subviews>
                                            <imageView clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleAspectFit" horizontalHuggingPriority="1000" verticalHuggingPriority="251" horizontalCompressionResistancePriority="1000" image="error_icon" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="3ZB-iI-gLf">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="18" height="18"/>
                                                <color key="tintColor" red="0.83921568629999999" green="0.1215686275" blue="0.15686274510000001" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
                                                <constraints>
                                                    <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="18" id="d3z-Sv-gqu"/>
                                                    <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="18" id="k9u-2l-qtm"/>
                                                </constraints>
                                            </imageView>
                                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="750" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Error MessageError " lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" numberOfLines="2" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="LZq-ZM-I8M">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="24" y="0.5" width="326" height="17"/>
                                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="14"/>
                                                <color key="textColor" red="0.83921568629999999" green="0.1215686275" blue="0.15686274510000001" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
                                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                            </label>
                                        </subviews>
                                    </stackView>
                                </subviews>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="SQQ-H3-h7m" secondAttribute="trailing" id="Ep2-Qb-ifT"/>
                                </constraints>
                            </stackView>
                            <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" axis="vertical" alignment="top" spacing="28" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="X9l-Yt-GDh" userLabel="OutBStackView">
                                <rect key="frame" x="32" y="168" width="350" height="18"/>
                                <subviews>
                                    <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" alignment="center" spacing="6" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="T1f-2Y-yyk" userLabel="InBStackView">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="153.5" height="18"/>
                                        <subviews>
                                            <imageView clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleAspectFit" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" image="error_icon" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Gag-ed-tZe">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="18" height="18"/>
                                                <constraints>
                                                    <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="18" id="K4g-4E-K0p"/>
                                                    <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="18" id="PBr-z0-jpn"/>
                                                </constraints>
                                            </imageView>
                                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Error MessageError " textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="TZP-DH-uI5">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="24" y="0.5" width="129.5" height="17"/>
                                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="14"/>
                                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                            </label>
                                        </subviews>
                                    </stackView>
                                </subviews>
                            </stackView>
                        </subviews>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="xhW-Es-C8j"/>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemBackgroundColor"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="X9l-Yt-GDh" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="xhW-Es-C8j" secondAttribute="leading" constant="32" id="4hM-RL-A5Y"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="X9l-Yt-GDh" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="xhW-Es-C8j" secondAttribute="top" constant="120" id="5MU-qV-xpr"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="ENa-iE-NqQ" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="xhW-Es-C8j" secondAttribute="top" constant="78" id="Ls6-Zc-vhb"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="xhW-Es-C8j" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="ENa-iE-NqQ" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="32" id="Num-3Y-VqY"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="xhW-Es-C8j" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="X9l-Yt-GDh" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="32" id="ThE-eV-YzW"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="ENa-iE-NqQ" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="xhW-Es-C8j" secondAttribute="leading" constant="32" id="thN-sH-6Ch"/>
                        </constraints>
                    </view>
                    <connections>
                        <outlet property="stackView" destination="ENa-iE-NqQ" id="hkf-7f-Rvn"/>
                    </connections>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="SCk-9R-e7I" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="1484" y="117"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
    <resources>
        <image name="error_icon" width="18" height="18"/>
        <systemColor name="systemBackgroundColor">
            <color white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
        </systemColor>
    </resources>
</document>
```

Comment: Thanks. I've already fixed those issues. I know some things are wrong. Actually, this question is not a "how to fix layout issues" question. What I'm trying to learn is how is this possible with two different devices. I've tried on physical iPhone 11. As expected, it didn't work. But if I didn't try it on the iPhone 11, it would go to store with this bug. Thank you for your effort though.